# Django Rest Framework – Custom Hyperlink field in serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

How can I add a custom hyperlink field in a serializer? I would like to have a hyperlink field in my serializer that has query params in it. Since there is no way to pass query params from `HyperlinkedRelatedField` or `HyperlinkedIdentityField` as far as I know, I've tried using a `SerializerMethodField`. However, this only serializes to a string, and is not a clickable URL when I visit the API through my browser. My code looks something like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    custom_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('url', 'custom_field')

    def get_custom_field(self, obj):
        result = '{}?{}'.format(
            reverse('my-view'),
            urllib.urlencode({'param': 'foo'})
        )
        return result
```

Also, I am having trouble understanding the difference between a `HyperlinkedRelatedField` and a `HyperlinkedIdentityField`, so a brief explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You must read..
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/

its help you. :-)

Comment: I have read it, it does not talk about custom hyperlinks

Comment: @b_pcakes - Mind accepting my answer if it meets your expectations? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This should do the trick:

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    custom_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('url', 'custom_field')

    def get_custom_field(self, obj):
        result = '{}?{}'.format(
            reverse('my-view', args=[obj.id], request=self.context['request']),
            'param=foo'
        )
        return result
```

The reverse function in rest_framework takes a view name (whatever view you'd like to link to), either an args list (the object id, in this case) or kwargs, and a request object (which can be accessed inside the serializer at `self.context['request']`).  It can additionally take a format parameter and any extra parameters (as a dictionary) that you want to pass to it.

The reverse function then builds a nice, fully-formed URL for you.  You can add query params to it by simply adding as many `?{}&{}&{}` to your result variable and then filling in the series of query params beneath the 'param=foo' inside your `format` function with whatever other params you want.

The `HyperlinkedIdentityField` is used on the object itself that is being serialized.  So a `HyperlinkedIdentifyField` is being used in place of your primary key field on `MyModel` because you are using a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` which creates a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` for the pk of the object itself being serialized.

The `HyperlinkedRelatedField` is used to define hyperlinked relationships to RELATED objects.  So if there were a `MySecondModel` with a foreign key relationship to `MyModel` and you wanted to have a hyperlink on your `MyModel` serializer to all the related `MySecondModel` objects you would use a `HyperlinkedRelatedField` like so (remember to add the new field to your fields attribute in Meta):

```
class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    custom_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    mysecondmodels = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True
        read_only=True,
        view_name='mysecondmodel-detail'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('url', 'custom_field', 'mysecondmodels')

    def get_custom_field(self, obj):
        result = '{}?{}'.format(
            reverse('my-view', args=[obj.id], request=self.context['request']),
            'param=foo'
        )
        return result
```

If it were a OneToOneField rather than ForeignKey field on `MySecondModel` then you would set many=False.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I receive KeyError for key 'request'. What to do to have self.context['request'] as you say?

Comment: @mirek When you use your serializer in a view you need to add context:
`MySerializer(MyModel, context={'request': request})`. If you're using a `ModelViewSet`
`self.request` or override `get_serializer_context`.